# Android JSON null pointer Exception while parsing

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception

I am beginner to android .I am making one application related to webservice.I am getting json by hitting url and I want to show in listview .I tried so many ways but no result.I got json exceptions.please help me
Here is my json:

```
    [
    [
    {
    "id":"9637",
    "country":"Australia",
    "time":"14:00",
    "type":"country",
    "status":"good"
    },
    {
    "id":"9638",
    "country":"india",
    "time":"16:00",
    "type":"country",
    "status":"good"
    }
    ]
    ]
code:
class Response extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,jsonResponse,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+jsonArray.length(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            //  JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.get


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
```

Comment: Where's the code, where's the exception stacktrace?

Comment: your missing a quote @  `"status":"good"`

Comment: post your code about processing the json string

Comment: @shayan are your sure `status` is `"status"` because the mistake was in both??

Comment: @MDMalik no i'm not sure, i just edit that because i think that it's write mistake,

Comment: I copied in jsonlint.com it is showing valid json

Comment: ya so based on @user3370656 it looks like the jsonlint.com has issue in producing JSON. Can we see the code?

Comment: @user3370656 i copied your json and that say is not valid because you missing a quote on both `status`,

Comment: I added the code and i got the result ,thanks for help

Comment: Please identify what line in your code is throwing the exception.

Comment: I got the result,I parsed the json successfully

Answer (score 1):

I think this code is correct:

```
        try {
            JSONArray json=new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
            JSONArray jsonArray=json.getJSONArray(0);
            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+jsonArray.length(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        //  JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.get


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

because your JSON Response is an array of arrays.